# Start a class with redirected input

Tags: java, multithreading, redirect, process, stdout

I need to reformat the command-line logging of a Java app without touching the original app. I have all the code, so I've imported into my project.  What I would like to do is figure out a way to make a new Process() or Thread() and redirect STDOUT and STDIN from that Thread into a BufferedReader and a BufferedWriter.

I want to make a wrapper that will start a new Process(MyApp.Main(args)).  I just don't know how to do that because it's in the jar. ProcessBuilder wants a file to launch.   Is there some way I can isolate System.In and System.Out from a Thread?

I think it's cleanest to figure out a way to launch a thread and grab the System.Out/System.In from that.  How do I do it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a good solid  10 hours into this... here's what I came up with..   Piped Streams are what i need

```
    int BUFFER = 4096;
    PipedOutputStream toAppPipedOutputStream;
    PipedInputStream toAppPipedInputStream;

    static BufferedReader fromAppBufferedReaderfinal;
    BufferedOutputStream fromAppOutputStream;
    PipedOutputStream fromAppPipedOutputStream;
    PipedInputStream fromAppPipedInputStream;

    /* constructor sets up logging and parameters */


           try { 
                fromAppPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER);
                fromAppOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(new PipedOutputStream(fromAppPipedInputStream));
                fromAppBufferedReaderfinal=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromAppPipedInputStream));
                CASUAL.Log.out = new PrintStream(fromAppOutputStream);

                toAppPipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER);
                toAppPipedOutputStream=new PipedOutputStream(toAppPipedInputStream);
                CASUAL.CASUALInteraction.in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toAppPipedInputStream));
```

in my log and output classes I am, by default, writing into a buffered reader/writer that is pointing at System.in.  I can hyjack it because it's a public static and this is possible.  Now I can just read and write to my app as though it were running on the command line inside my own app

Comment: @CJxD  What do you mean?  This is it.  CASUAL.Log.out is a reference to System.out which my program always uses to communicate and CASUAL.CASUALInteractionl.in is a reference to System.in.    This hijacks those references and redirects them into another app.    It would be possible to do the same to System.in and System.out by replacing them instead.